# Why can't we stick with a consistent notation for both QM and GR?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, conventions, notation

In QM, there's stuff like $\langle a | H| b \rangle$. In GR, the same stuff is $H_{ab} v^a w  ^b$. In QM, there's $|a\rangle \langle a|$. In GR, the same stuff is $v^a v_b$. In QM, linear operators are defined as taking one vector and giving another vector. In GR, the same thing is defined as a tensor taking two vectors and giving a number. It's so difficult to draw connections. Why not be consistent?

Comment: I could pretend I'm able to write a good answer, but I know I won't match this beautiful piece by Terry Tao at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/a/366118. In summary, because each context has different properties. You want to use notation that makes the calculations of each context easier. QM calculations and GR calculations are quite different, so they get easier when done in different notations.

Comment: @NickolasAlves Much thanks. Didn't know Terry Tao used this site.